# Issue with Double clicks on a element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have running script which moves the tr elements from one container to another on double click. But **i have below mentioned issues:**

**1) If we do are very quick double-click on elements than it moves but its values doesn't come, it shows empty tags.

2) I want to change the background color on double click and it color should remove when we click outside or another elements.**

[image]

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        function initTabelMgmt() {
            selectInvitees();
            moveSelectedInvitees();
            deleteInvitees();
            //scrollOpen();
        }
        var tmContainer = $("div.cv-tm-body");
        var toggleAssignBtn = tmContainer.find('.cv-move-items button');
        /*
        function scrollOpen() {
            var position = $('div.cv-item li.open').first().position();
            var offsetTop = $('div.cv-tm-col-r .cv-helper-grid-overflow').scrollTop();
            var unitHeight = $('div.cv-item li.open').first().height();
            var containerHeight = $('div.cv-tm-col-r .cv-helper-grid-overflow').height();
            var scrollAmount = offsetTop + position.top;


            if ((offsetTop - position.top) <= 0 && (offsetTop - position.top) >= (-containerHeight + unitHeight)) {

                //do nothing
            } else {  
                $('div.cv-tm-col-r .cv-helper-grid-overflow').animate({
                    scrollTop: scrollAmount

                });

            }
        };
        */
        // scrollOpen end
        function selectInvitees() {
            //select items from invitee list
            var startIndex, endIndex;
            var dbclick = false;
            tmContainer.find("table.cv-invitees").on('click', 'tr', function (e) {

                var row = $(this);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    //singleclick functionality start.
                    if (dbclick == false) {
                        if (!row.is('.assigned')) {
                             toggleAssignBtn.removeClass('is-disabled');
                            if (e.shiftKey) {
                                row.parents('.cv-invitees').find('tr').removeClass('selected');
                                endIndex = row.parents('.cv-invitees').find('tr').index(this);
                                var range = row.closest('table').find('tr').slice(Math.min(startIndex, endIndex), Math.max(startIndex, endIndex) + 1).not('.assigned');
                                range.addClass('selected');
                            } else if (e.ctrlKey) {
                                startIndex = row.parents('.cv-invitees').find('tr').index(this);
                                row.toggleClass('selected');
                            } else {
                                startIndex = row.parents('.cv-invitees').find('tr').index(this);
                                row.parents('.cv-invitees').find('tr').not(this).removeClass('selected');
                                row.toggleClass('selected');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, 200)
            })
                .dblclick(function () {
                    dbclick = true
                    //doubleclick functionality start.
                    toggleAssignBtn.addClass('is-disabled');
                    function moveSelectedInviteesDBClick() {
                         var row = tmContainer.find("table.cv-invitees tr.selected");

                        if (!row.is('.assigned')) {
                            var allOpenSeat = $('.cv-item .open');
                            var numberOpen = allOpenSeat.length;
                            var name = row.find("td").eq(0).text();;
                            var company = row.find("td").eq(1).text();
                            var addedInvitees = [];

                            allOpenSeat.each(function (index) {
                                if (index < 1) {
                                    var openSeat = $(this);
                                    openSeat.find('.name').text(name);
                                    if (company != '') {
                                        openSeat.find('.company').addClass('show').text(company);
                                    }
                                    var seatAssignment = new Object();
                                    seatAssignment.company = "";
                                    addedInvitees.push(seatAssignment);
                                    openSeat.removeClass('open');
                                }
                                row.remove();
                            });
                        }
                    } // moveSelectedInviteesDBClick
                    moveSelectedInviteesDBClick();
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        dbclick = false
                    }, 300)
                });
        } // selectInvitees end

        function moveSelectedInvitees() {
            //move invitees from left to right
            tmContainer.find('button.cvf-moveright').click(function () {
                var selectedItem = $('.cv-invitees .selected');
                var allOpenSeat = $('.cv-item .open');
                var numberSelected = selectedItem.length;
                var numberOpen = allOpenSeat.length;
                var errorMsg = tmContainer.prev('.cv-alert-error');
                if (numberSelected > numberOpen) {
                    errorMsg.removeClass('is-hidden');
                } else {
                    var name;
                    var company;
                    var invitee = [];
                    var selectedInvitees = [];
                    var count = 0;
                    selectedItem.each(function () {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        name = $this.find("td").eq(0).text();
                        company = $this.find("td").eq(1).text();
                        invitee = [name, company];
                        selectedInvitees.push(invitee);
                        count = count + 1;
                        i = 0;
                        $this.remove();
                    });
                    var addedInvitees = [];
                    var items = $('div.cv-item li');
                    var seatItems = $('div.cv-order li');
                    allOpenSeat.each(function (index) {
                        if (index < count) {
                            var openSeat = $(this);
                            openSeat.find('.name').text(selectedInvitees[index][0]);
                            if (selectedInvitees[index][1] != '') {
                                openSeat.find('.company').addClass('show').text(selectedInvitees[index][1]);
                            }
                            var seatAssignment = new Object();
                            seatAssignment.company = "";
                            addedInvitees.push(seatAssignment);
                            //selectedInvitees.shift();
                            openSeat.removeClass('open');
                        }
                    });
                    selectedInvitees = [];
                }
                toggleAssignBtn.addClass('is-disabled');
            });
        } // moveSelectedInvitees end

        function deleteInvitees() {
            //move invitees from left to right
            tmContainer.find('div.cv-tm-col-r .cv-icon-remove').click(function () {
                //delete seat assignment
                var icon = $(this);
                var idx = $('.ui-sortable li').index(icon.parent());
                icon.parent().fadeTo(0, 0).addClass('open').find('.name').text('Open').end().fadeTo(750, 1);
                icon.parent().find('.company').removeClass('show').text('');
                // icon.parent().find('.entitystub').text('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000');
                // icon.parent().find('.entitytype').text('0');
                // icon.parent().find('.pipe').remove();
                // icon.hide();
                //  var testSeat = $('.seat-numbers li').get(idx);
                //var seatStub = j$.trim(j$(testSeat).find('.seatstub').text());
                //var input = { 'seatStub': seatStub };
                //AssignSeats(input, "/Subscribers/WS/SeatAssignmentService.asmx/DeleteRegistrant");
            });
        }
        initTabelMgmt();
    }); // document.ready end

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks pretty nice. You should also use in order to register from jQuery a single click event the native method .click(...). So please change the following line

```
tmContainer.find("table.cv-invitees").on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
```

To:

```
tmContainer.find("table.cv-invitees").click(function (e) {
```

and everything should work fine. For some strange reasons the function

```
$("#someelement").on("click", ...);
```

does not work always, only sometimes. JQuery officially recommends you to use the native functions for predefined events (such as onclick, onkeyup, onchange etc.) because of this strange behavior.

Edit:
If dblick does not work now, then make 2 lines please, like this:

```
tmContainer.find("table.cv-invitees").click(function (e) {
// [...]
;
tmContainer.find("table.cv-invitees").dbclick(function (e) {
// [...]
```

Edit2:
If it does not work, too, then please remove the single click event listener when you are in the .click() closure. Because if this happens, jQuery´s behavior is to treat it always as a single click. So, in other words dblick() will never be triggered, because .click() will always happens before. And then jQuery won´t count up to 2 fast clicks. Expect the unexpected^^

Edit3: This is the full code, which should hopefully work now as it is:

```
$(function ()
  {
    function initTabelMgmt()
    {
        selectInvitees();
        moveSelectedInvitees();
        deleteInvitees();
        //scrollOpen();
    }
    var tmContainer = $("div.cv-tm-body");
    var toggleAssignBtn = tmContainer.find('.cv-move-items button');
    var iClickCounter = 0;
    var dtFirstClick, dtSecondClick;
    /*
    function scrollOpen() {
        var position = $('div.cv-item li.open').first().position();
        var offsetTop = $('div.cv-tm-col-r .cv-helper-grid-overflow').scrollTop();
        var unitHeight = $('div.cv-item li.open').first().height();
        var containerHeight = $('div.cv-tm-col-r .cv-helper-grid-overflow').height();
        var scrollAmount = offsetTop + position.top;


        if ((offsetTop - position.top) <= 0 && (offsetTop - position.top) >= (-containerHeight + unitHeight)) {

            //do nothing
        } else {  
            $('div.cv-tm-col-r .cv-helper-grid-overflow').animate({
                scrollTop: scrollAmount

            });

        }
    };
    */
    // scrollOpen end
    function selectInvitees()
    {
        //select items from invitee list
        var startIndex, endIndex;
        var dbclick = false;
        tmContainer.find("table.cv-invitees").click(function(e)
                                                 {
                                                    iClickCounter++;
                                                    if (iClickCounter === 1)
                                                    {
                                                        dtFirstClick = new Date();
                                                        var row = $(this);
                                                        window.setTimeout(function ()
                                                                        {
                                                                            //singleclick functionality start.
                                                                            if (dbclick == false)
                                                                            {
                                                                                if (!row.is('.assigned'))
                                                                                {
                                                                                     toggleAssignBtn.removeClass('is-disabled');
                                                                                    if (e.shiftKey)
                                                                                    {
                                                                                       row.parents('.cv-invitees').find('tr').removeClass('selected');
                                                                                       endIndex = row.parents('.cv-invitees').find('tr').index(this);
                                                                                       var range = row.closest('table').find('tr').slice(Math.min(startIndex, endIndex), Math.max(startIndex, endIndex) + 1).not('.assigned');
                                                                                       range.addClass('selected');
                                                                                    }
                                                                                    else if (e.ctrlKey)
                                                                                    {
                                                                                       startIndex = row.parents('.cv-invitees').find('tr').index(this);
                                                                                       row.toggleClass('selected');
                                                                                    }
                                                                                    else
                                                                                    {
                                                                                       startIndex = row.parents('.cv-invitees').find('tr').index(this);
                                                                                       row.parents('.cv-invitees').find('tr').not(this).removeClass('selected');
                                                                                       row.toggleClass('selected');
                                                                                    }
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        },
                                                                        200);
                                                    }
                                                    else if (iClickCounter === 2)
                                                    {
                                                        dtSecondClick = new Date();
                                                    }
                                                    else if (iClickCounter === 3)
                                                    {
                                                        if (dtSecondClick.getTime() - dtFirstClick.getTime() < 1000)
                                                        {
                                                            return;
                                                        }

                                                        iClickCounter = 0;
                                                        dbclick = true
                                                        //doubleclick functionality start.
                                                        toggleAssignBtn.addClass('is-disabled');
                                                        function moveSelectedInviteesDBClick()
                                                        {
                                                            var row = tmContainer.find("table.cv-invitees tr.selected");

                                                            if (!row.is('.assigned'))
                                                            {
                                                                var allOpenSeat = $('.cv-item .open');
                                                                var numberOpen = allOpenSeat.length;
                                                                var name = row.find("td").eq(0).text();;
                                                                var company = row.find("td").eq(1).text();
                                                                var addedInvitees = [];

                                                                allOpenSeat.each(function (index)
                                                                                 {
                                                                                    if (index < 1)
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        var openSeat = $(this);
                                                                                        openSeat.find('.name').text(name);
                                                                                        if (company != '') {
                                                                                            openSeat.find('.company').addClass('show').text(company);
                                                                                        }
                                                                                        var seatAssignment = new Object();
                                                                                        seatAssignment.company = "";
                                                                                        addedInvitees.push(seatAssignment);
                                                                                        openSeat.removeClass('open');
                                                                                    }
                                                                                    row.remove();
                                                                                }
                                                                );
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        // moveSelectedInviteesDBClick
                                                        moveSelectedInviteesDBClick();
                                                        window.setTimeout(function ()
                                                                        {
                                                                            dbclick = false
                                                                        }, 300);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            );
    } // selectInvitees end

    function moveSelectedInvitees()
    {
        //move invitees from left to right
        tmContainer.find('button.cvf-moveright').click(function ()
                                                       {
                                                            var selectedItem = $('.cv-invitees .selected');
                                                            var allOpenSeat = $('.cv-item .open');
                                                            var numberSelected = selectedItem.length;
                                                            var numberOpen = allOpenSeat.length;
                                                            var errorMsg = tmContainer.prev('.cv-alert-error');
                                                            if (numberSelected > numberOpen) {
                                                                errorMsg.removeClass('is-hidden');
                                                            }
                                                            else
                                                            {
                                                                var name;
                                                                var company;
                                                                var invitee = [];
                                                                var selectedInvitees = [];
                                                                var count = 0;
                                                                selectedItem.each(function () {
                                                                    var $this = $(this);
                                                                    name = $this.find("td").eq(0).text();
                                                                    company = $this.find("td").eq(1).text();
                                                                    invitee = [name, company];
                                                                    selectedInvitees.push(invitee);
                                                                    count = count + 1;
                                                                    i = 0;
                                                                    $this.remove();
                                                                });
                                                                var addedInvitees = [];
                                                                var items = $('div.cv-item li');
                                                                var seatItems = $('div.cv-order li');
                                                                allOpenSeat.each(function (index)
                                                                                 {
                                                                                    if (index < count)
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        var openSeat = $(this);
                                                                                        openSeat.find('.name').text(selectedInvitees[index][0]);
                                                                                        if (selectedInvitees[index][1] != '')
                                                                                        {
                                                                                            openSeat.find('.company').addClass('show').text(selectedInvitees[index][1]);
                                                                                        }
                                                                                        var seatAssignment = new Object();
                                                                                        seatAssignment.company = "";
                                                                                        addedInvitees.push(seatAssignment);
                                                                                        //selectedInvitees.shift();
                                                                                        openSeat.removeClass('open');
                                                                                    }
                                                                                }
                                                                );
                                                                selectedInvitees = [];
                                                            }
                                                            toggleAssignBtn.addClass('is-disabled');
                                                        }
                                                );
    } // moveSelectedInvitees end

    function deleteInvitees()
    {
        //move invitees from left to right
        tmContainer.find('div.cv-tm-col-r .cv-icon-remove').click(function ()
                                                                  {
                                                                    //delete seat assignment
                                                                    var icon = $(this);
                                                                    var idx = $('.ui-sortable li').index(icon.parent());
                                                                    icon.parent().fadeTo(0, 0).addClass('open').find('.name').text('Open').end().fadeTo(750, 1);
                                                                    icon.parent().find('.company').removeClass('show').text('');
                                                                    // icon.parent().find('.entitystub').text('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000');
                                                                    // icon.parent().find('.entitytype').text('0');
                                                                    // icon.parent().find('.pipe').remove();
                                                                    // icon.hide();
                                                                    //  var testSeat = $('.seat-numbers li').get(idx);
                                                                    //var seatStub = j$.trim(j$(testSeat).find('.seatstub').text());
                                                                    //var input = { 'seatStub': seatStub };
                                                                    //AssignSeats(input, "/Subscribers/WS/SeatAssignmentService.asmx/DeleteRegistrant");
                                                                }
                                                            );
    }
    initTabelMgmt();
}
); // document.ready end
```

I guess that you interpret in your special case a double click as 3 times clicked at the same table entry. And if a user do so and if the time difference between first and second click is longer than one second, a double click will be fired. I think should be the solution to deal with this special case.

Edit 4: Please test, if it is possible to click on 3 different table column and get also double click fired. I think this is an disadvantage on how my code handles the double click. So, you need to know from which table column you have already 1 to 3 clicks set. How can we do this? Basically, there are 3 possibilities to do this:

1. (HTML5 only:) Make data attribute on each tr and the value for this data attribute
   should be the clicks already clicke on this tr.
2. Define a global object key/value pair object, which holds the
   event-ID (but I don´t know how to get this back by jQuery driven
   events) as the key and the amount of clicks already done as the
   value. And then if you are on the next click, you can decide what is
   to do now for this tr. This is my favorite alternative!
3. Last but not least: Only register the click event on every tr and
   make for each click-registering an own global area, so that we just
   avoid the actual problem. You can do this e. g. by making an JS
   Object which hold a member variable as the iclickCounter and you
   make a new object of this class, each time a new click event is
   registered. But this alternative need a lot more code and is main-memory-hungry.

All of thes possible options need a wrap around your click event, e. g. a loop, that iterates over all tr elements in the given table. You did this already partially by calling the jQuery-function .find(..). This executes the closure on every found html element. So, in your case on all tr elements in the searched table. But what you need to do is to make the workaround of one of my options given above.

Comment: Thanks @alpham for your effort but now the double click functionality not working...

Comment: I need the single click behavior as single click functionalty also works, we have assign button for this case..can you please paste the whole correct code..so it would be easy for me to try